# Access form load speed containing multiple continuous subforms

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, subform

I have a form that consists of 14 continuous subforms (calendar format). The subforms start out with no record source, and I have VBA code cycles through the controls and sets the recordset data from SQL Server (through linked tables) through the line `Me.RecordSource = [tSQL query string]`. Everything runs on the local network. There are about 4000 records in the table and each subform will contain 40 records on average. I also have conditional formatting to change control colors. The form takes about 3-4 seconds to load when I refresh it. Is this normal? Is there a way to speed this up? My goal is to switch to cloud SQL, but if it takes 3 seconds locally, It's not going to be an acceptable speed through the cloud.

Comment: CF can really slow down. Remove that and see if it makes a change.

Comment: I find SQL server can be slow to communicate with Access, especially compared to native operations, though that depends on the network speed. Queries on large sets seem exponentially slower than smaller queries. I find if the user is in control though the delay is more acceptable, so consider having the user click a button to get the data, rather than automatically getting the data and then having them wait for the form to load.

Comment: I cannot remove the CF, as they apply color to each record and the application is highly dependent on colorization. And I'd rather have the calendar load than open up completely blank and have the users click the refresh button. Either way it will need to load the data.